# Different results for KIF automated tests when built from xcodebiuld on the command line?

Tags: iphone, ios, automated-tests, kif

I have KIF installed and running in my iPhone project and I've created a bunch of test that pass perfectly when I run via XCode. When I build the same project and target using xcodebuild on the command line, some of the tests that pick items from a UIPickerView fail in the following way:

```
2013-02-02 18:46:55.950 SmartRoamAcceptanceTests[31224:c07] PASS (0.84s): Tap view with accessibility label "Choose Country"
2013-02-02 18:46:55.978 SmartRoamAcceptanceTests[31224:c07] FAIL (0.03s): Select the "United States (+1)" item from the picker
2013-02-02 18:46:55.979 SmartRoamAcceptanceTests[31224:c07] FAILING ERROR: Error Domain=KIFTest Code=0 "Failed to find picker view value with title "United States (+1)"" UserInfo=0xd01c160 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to find picker view value with title "United States (+1)"}
```

These tests work perfectly if built from XCode IDE. What could be different?

Comment: Kirby, did you ever determine what this issue was?